# Why an AJAX call is giving an error timeout response only in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**My ajax call**

I make an ajax call to check if the e-mail address is already used to participate. The php-file returns 0 when it is not used and 1 if it is already used. When it is used it'll make an error label to say so.

This works perfectly in Chrome, Safari, Internet Explorer. But is a complete pain in the ass in Firefox. It checks and gives the correct response, but after 5 seconds it gives a timeout.

I have another ajax call to put all the data in the database and it has the exact same problem.

What do I do wrong?

```
function controleerDeelnemerEmail(){

    var emailVal = $('#email').val();

    $.ajax( {

        type: 'POST',
        url:'?page=home&action=check',
        dataType:'text',
        data: {'email':emailVal}, 
        success: function( data ){

            data = parseInt(data);

            if(data == 1){

                if( $(".emailerror").length == 0 ){
                    var error = "<label for='email' generated='true' class='error emailerror' style=''>Dit e-mailadres wordt al gebruikt</label>"
                    $(error).insertBefore( $('#email') );    
                }                            
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Server Side**

public function check(){

```
    if(!empty($_POST)){

        $content = $this->deelnemerDAO->controleerDeelnemerEmail( $_POST['email'] );

        if( $content == 1 ){
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 0;
        }
        exit();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an error callback to see if the answer returned is one.

A wrong type can be considered as an error by ajax.

```
function controleerDeelnemerEmail() {
    var emailVal = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'?page=home&action=check',
        dataType:'text',
        data: {
            'email': emailVal
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        // equivalent to success callback
        data = parseInt(data);
        if (data == 1) {
            if ($(".emailerror").length === 0) {
                var error = $("<label>", {
                    'for': 'email',
                    'generated': 'true',
                    'class': 'error emailerror'
                }).text("Dit e-mailadres wordt al gebruikt").insertBefore($('#email'));
            }                            
        }
    }).fail(function (response, status) {
        alert('fail');
    });
}
```

Comment: My errorhandling is handled by 

$.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error: [' + textStatus + '] ' + errorThrown + ' : ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });

This throws the timeout.

Comment: Believe it or not... It works now.
You're my hero! ^^

Although I do not completely understand why. You're just put it differently than me. Or not?

Comment: No problem, if it's working you can accept the answer :)
According to the jQuery documentation for $.ajaxSetup:
> Description: Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is not recommended.

Comment: I read it today. Strange enough that is how I was thaught. Good to know. Thanks again!

Comment: And about Ajax:

Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: Strange enough, now it's not working anymore... Editing the original post with server side code.

Comment: Okay, did you completely remove your $.ajaxSetup ? Do you get something on .done() or .error() callbacks ?

Comment: I removed the ajaxSetup. Now it's giving nothing at all. Is not getting in the done or fail. In Firefox that is, other browsers doing still OK...

Comment: Hummmm this is definitely strange, what about your environment ? Are you trying in a localhost ?
EDIT: I had a forgotten comma after the data object, you should remove it to properly end your object.
Do you have some informations in Mozilla firebug or web console ?

Comment: No. It's on a server... I have a laptop of my work with firefox 3 or something. And that is not giving any problems as well.

Comment: Firefox 3 ? You may have some small updates to do, I mean, right now !
http://www.mozilla.org/

Comment: This is what I see in my firefox console: POST [theurl] - 200 OK 83ms

Comment: So your "done" callback should be triggered.
What if you add a console.log() or alert() at the beginning of this callback ?

Comment: Lolz... I know. It's not mine. Need some administrator rights... But on my macbook I'm completely up-to-date ;)

Comment: Nothing... It's not triggered
If you want to try: [link]http://web.rodekruis.be/formulieren/rodekruis/14daagse/

Comment: gosh, and you don't have any syntax error ? And if you add a .always() callback after .fail() ? Do you get something ?

Comment: Okay check the line so ! Isn't it this "," story after data params, that I removed by editing my answer ?

Comment: Hummmm I just didn't see that but... What if you convert your answer to string ????
echo '1'; and echo '0'; instead of echo 1; and echo 0; ?

Comment: No... Did that already. Also tries the .always() callback, returning nothing. But the error console of the webdeveloper toolbar is giving me that empty error.

Comment: And you still get nothing on Chrome ?
Do you still see the network call ? POST [theurl] - 200 OK ?
And more that the webdeveloper console, in Firebug plugin, I mean when you right-click then inspect element and see the console, what do you have ?

Comment: Chrome is doing its job well. It enters the done function. Firefox only gives errors in the webdeveloper console, not in the firebug plugin. But not a linenumber. I see other errors (from the firebug plugin) with linenumbers. So odd...

Comment: Do you have the latest firefox?

Comment: Yeah, version 20.0 on mac OS X 10.8.3. I don't speak your website language but I seem to not have any error... ?!

Comment: Can you fill in carolina.droogendijk@gmail.com in e-mail - then you should get an error: 'u heeft dit mailadres al gebruikt'...

Comment: Yep I get this message, aswell as in Chrome :)

Comment: You're kidding me... So it's just with me?

Comment: I could die... But most of all I'm really happy :)
And thankful that you just kept giving solutions :)

Comment: Haha yeah that's very strange...
Did you clear your browser / server cache ??

Comment: Kinda keen on clearing browser cache. Bit freaky about it. So yes. Dunno what it is... Could it be an extension bugging my browser? It is an extension. Switched them all off and now it's working... Grr

Comment: Did you try to eat an apple, drink a cup of tea, close your eyes counting until 19 retaining your respiration ?

Comment: Lolz... I think some sleep would help a lot ;) What do I have to do know. Give the stupid answer and assign it as the correct one? :)

Comment: It could help you in another night if you still have this problem :)

Comment: This was enough excitement for one night. But thanks a million! ^^